How to use Input Text with Tab Character (\t) using Robocorp (Robot Framework)?
I'm having trouble with Input text with a tab character in a text box.
The following works perfectly fine with the newline character (\n), but I can't seem to find a tab character (\t)
Input Text    stPasteData-inputEl    abc${\n}abc

Anyone has any idea?
Thanks!

Robot framework builtin libraries do not have "Input Text" keyword, what library are you talking about ?

Hi @tzehuai, not sure what library you are using but for example in SeleniumLibrary, you can use the Press Key keyword. Here are the list of keys that can be used with the keyword.

@rasjani I'm using Selenium

@Pramesh Yes you're right I'm using the SeleniumLibrary. Thanks for the pointer! I'll try that out.
